# Overlapping elements in a responsive site design

Tags: html, css, overlapping, skeleton-css-boilerplate, responsive

I have to code something like this in html/css (I'm also using the Skeleton framework):
[design preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU0Vk.png)

I tried lots of ways to make the background and the image overlap and used absolute positioning for the image. Not sure if it's the best option, especially since when I change the width of the browser the design starts to fall apart, and I want it to be responsive.
Is there a better way to implement this? If not, how do I make the image vertically centered with regard to the gray background. Thank you!

Here are the html/css files + skeleton and the image (for testing purposes): [Dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/64wdo1b1me51vou/AAAJfV0EtDfHuftiRr6Ddy0Za?dl=0)

And here's the pure code. HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="news twelve columns">
      <div class="imgcont seven columns">
        <img src="newsimg.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="newsimage ten columns">
        <div class="newstext six columns">
          <div class="row">
            <h2>Latest News</h2>
            <h3>New video coming out soon!</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="more"><a href="#">MORE</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```css
.news{
 margin-top: 3.125em;
}
.newsimage{
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 background-color: #594f4e;
 height: 100%;
}
.imgcont{
 position: absolute;
 top: 6em;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 200;
}
.newstext{
 float:right;
}
.newstext h2{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 2.6em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 float: right;
 padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0 0;
 letter-spacing: 0.02em;
}
.newstext h3{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 2.35em;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 0.5em 0 0;
 line-height: 1.2em;
}
.newstext p{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55em;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 1em 0 0;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.more{
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #716960;
 margin: 0 1em 1em auto;
 float: right;
}
.more a{
 display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.35em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.03em;
 float: right;

}

img{max-width:100%;}

h1, h2, h3, p{
  color: white; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, probably there is a better solution, i dont know skeleton.css
HTML-Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row custom">
    <div class="news nine columns">
        <div class="newstext six columns">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS-Code:

```
.row.custom {
    background: url(newsimg.jpg);
    background-size: 40% 60%;
    background-position: 20% center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 50px auto;  
}

.news.nine.columns {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #594f4e;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

You have to adjust background-size, background-position...
Explanation:https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-position/ https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

After that you need to add media queries to your CSS-Code, to adjust your design for smaller screens: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp